# Symfony PHPUnit Test ( error 500 )

Tags: php, json, unit-testing, symfony, content-type

Im testing this function

```
/**
* @Route("/list", name="_clients")
* @Method("GET")
*/
public function ClientsAction()
{
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $data = $em->getRepository('InvoiceBundle:Clients')->findByUser($this->user());
   if($data){
     $Clients = array();
     foreach($data as $v){
        if($v->getCompanyId() != 0 ) {
           $companyId = $v->getCompanyId();
        } else {
           $companyId = '';
        }

        if ($v->getClient() == 'person'){
           $company = $v->getName().' '.$v->getLname();
        } else {
           $company = $v->getCompany();
        }

        $Clients[] = array(
          'id' => $v->getId(),
          'settings' => $company,
          'companyId' => $companyId,
          'client' => $v->getClient(),
          'mobile' => $v->getMobile(),
          'email' => $v->getEmail(),
          'clientName' => $v->getClientName(),
          'delivery' => $v->getDelivery(),
          'ContactPerson' => $v->getContactPerson()
       );
     }
   } else {
      $Clients = array('data' => 'empty');
   }

   $response = new JsonResponse($Clients);
   return $response;
}
```

The function it self runs correctly , but then i want to check if my 'Content-Type' is Json with this function

```
public function testClients()
{
   $client = static::createClient();

   $client->request('GET', '/clients/list');
   $this->assertTrue(
     $client->getResponse()->headers->contains(
       'Content-Type',
       'application/json'
     )
   );
}
```

with this i get a FALSE value.
Then i try to do a test for Status code

```
$this->assertSame(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

With this i get error 500 instead of 200 OK
I understand that is why i get a FALSE value in my 'Content-Type' test but i cant get why.
Im doing all this according to the Symfony documentation.
May be i'm doing something wrong or is it just that you cant check the 'Content-Type'?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Stupid question: is the URL correct?

Answer (score 2):

`JsonResponse` does add the Content-Type header (application/json) so this should not be an issue.

I think the main issue is that you are missing `$` on the `client->request()` line.

Edit :

Before the declaration of your class, did you add `@Route("/clients")` ?

Or, maybe the data returned by `findByUser` is not what you expected and calls to `$v` fail.

Comment: sorry copied it wrong it has $ but still same problem